# Using environment variables in Heroku release bash script

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, shell, heroku

I need to update a domain name in the static file when my app promoted to production. I've added this line to my Procfile:
`release: ./update-domain.sh`

Here is the content:

```
if [ -n "$DOMAIN" ]; then
  sed -i 's@$DOMAIN@'"$DOMAIN"'@' ./assets/config.json
fi
```

But it seems like Heroku doesn't have access to the env variables from bash. Is that true?

I'm not sure if that is related, but in Heroku Exec documentation I found this:

> The SSH session created by Heroku Exec will not have the config vars set as environment variables (i.e., env in a session will not list config vars set by heroku config:set).

Thank you.

Comment: So, I can access env variables. I think something is wrong with the file path.